# AJAX conditional inside append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I have an Ajax call to an API which retrieves a list of cars and their related specifications in a subset.  This displays in a div through my append.  I take a value default_spec_id and try to compare with the id of each car.  If it equal it sets a var defaultSet to 'checked'.

However it is not retrieving accurate results at all and the car's default spec is setting the checked status to the wrong checkbox.

My question essentially is, can I do this logic and how?

```
$.getJSON("{{ url('api/checkcars')}}", { option: $(this).val() }, 
function(data) {
    if ( data.success == true ) { 
        $.each(data.cars, function(key, value) { 
            var isDefault = data.default_spec_id;
            if (isDefault === value.id)  {
                defaultset =  'checked';
            } 
            $('#cars').append('<div><input type="radio" value="' + value.id +'" name="spec" ' +  defaultset +'> ' +  value.title +'</div>');
        });
    }
});
```

JSON

```
{
id: 7,
name: "renault clio",
default_spec_id: 8,
cars: [
   {
     id: 8,
     name: "Spec name 1",
     description: ""
     }
   },
   {
     id: 9,
     name: "Spec name 2",
     description: ""
   }
  }
 }
]
}
```

Comment: can you post json data

Comment: not sure if this is related but, is there any reason why you append `</p></div></div>` at the end? it seems that you have `<div><input>` to start with, and end tags are not matching.

Comment: instead of just appending `checked` use `checked="checked"`

Comment: Have updated with JSON. Thanks.  I'll tidy up the append too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a variable called `defaultset` with our `var` keyword.

so basically it will assign that to global scope.

Your code has to look like the below

```
$.getJSON("{{ url('api/checkcars')}}", { option: $(this).val() }, 
function(data) {
    if ( data.success == true ) { 
        $.each(data.cars, function(key, value) { 
            var isDefault = data.default_spec_id;
            var defaultset = "";
            if (isDefault === value.id)  {
                defaultset =  'checked';
            } 
            $('#cars').append('<div><input type="radio" value="' + value.id +'" name="spec" ' +  defaultset +'> ' +  value.title +'</div>');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, that simple. It's working great now.  Thank you so much.